# Custom discrete slider in Python/Django or D3

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, mpld3, matplotlib-widget

I'm working on a custom survey app for a small company intranet and would like to design custom sliders. I need to have discrete sliders that can indicate values from 1-5 but would allow you to select your level based on hover over and click actions. I've found discrete sliders for Python via matplotlib as well as D3, but nothing like this. I'd like it to look something like this:

[image: Slider Sample]

Is this kind of front end implementation better left to working in d3, or is a better course of action is to write a wrapper for the existing slider class in Python? Open to any and all suggestions, but I'm sticking with Django as the framework for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of scale I was evidently looking for is a "Likert field", rather than a discrete slider. Django has a package that can accomplish this:

https://pypi.org/project/django-likert-field/